# Ignore Apache Default Server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I run several `vhost`s on our Apache server. Whenever browse the server using either it's IP address or some other name that resolves to that address, but where a virtual host entry doesn't exist for that address I get the generic Apache test page:

[image]

I want to change the server so I can specify a Virtual Host to see by default instead of the Apache Default Server page. I don't want to just modify the Default Server page either. I just need to be able to specify a Virtual Host to use instead.

I added the following Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    DocumentRoot /vhosts/default/public
</VirtualHost>
```

What I am reading is supposed to take priority over all other Virtual Hosts as the default. But this doesn't seem to take priority over the Apache Default Server/Host.

What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That welcome page is generated by /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf.  If you remove/move away that file and restart/reload apache you won't be getting this welcome page anymore.

Comment: But then I just get the first vhost conf that is read by Apache. How do I manually specify EXACTLY which vhost I want to see by default instead?

Comment: Oh nevermind I guess I just answered my own question. Just created a `000-default.conf` that loads first. Thanks.